# Algorithmic complexity of Divide and Conquer and "work"?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

I been recently trying to teach my self algorithms from MIT Open-Course Ware. I was learning Divide and Conquer technique on a 1D array, to find a peak.

I understand the worst case complexity is O(log n), essentially how many times can you split the array in half.

I also understand the best case complexity is Omega(n), find a peak at n/2.

Two things i didn't understand was why is the complexity theta(log n) as well.

Also the lecturer said the work needed for this algorithm is as follows:

T(n) = T(n/2) + Θ(1) = Θ(1) + . . . + Θ(1) (log2(n) times) = Θ(log2(n))

can any explain these two problems for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My own opinion is that the question is somewhat tricky: they ask for a peak instead of global peak(this takes O(n)).

What you should notice is that: in any subarray, there exists a "peak". Since there must be a max value in any array, so at least one is found.

With this preparation, we can think like this:
If mid value is found to be a peak, then problem solved.
Otherwise, first consider whether mid value less than its left neighbour, if yes turn to left half array.
Otherwise, turn to right half array.

If once mid is of index 0, then last step: low index=0, high index=0 or 1, last mid index=1 or 2, arr[0]>arr[last mid(1)] or arr[1]> arr[last mid(2)]. For arr[1]> arr[last mid(2)], if arr[0]arr[0] and arr[2]. If arr[0]$\geq$arr[1], problems solved too.

Similarly, if index happens to be in the last, we are guaranteed to find one peak too.

What if in the middle? If mid value finally go to two sides, according to the following there must a peak. So we consider cases where low greater than 0 and high index less than n-1.

If one step shows that mid being the peak, problem solved too. Otherwise, since divide and conquer won't go forever, ultimately it will converges to only one index $mid_{final}$. For symmetry, we talk about only one case this time. In the "last step", mid value less than its left neighbour. 
That is to say:

Case 1: 
low>0, $arr[mid]<arr[mid-1]$, mid-low=1,then the next mid=low+(mid-1-low)/2=low, if $arr[low]<arr[low-1]$, game overs. But we argue this is impossible.Think about low index? How does it become greater than 0? Because in the previous steps, the $arr[mid]\geq arr[mid-1]$ but $arr[mid]\lt arr[mid-1]$, so from here the now low is the previous mid-1, hence now $arr[low]>arr[low-1]$, so $arr[low]<arr[low-1]$ is impossible.

Case 2:
low>0, $arr[mid]<arr[mid-1]$, mid-low=2,the arguing is similar.

For the equation part, this is easy:
T(n) = T(n/2) + Θ(1) = Θ(1) + . . . + Θ(1) (log2(n) times)
$T(n)=T(n/2)+\Theta (1)=T(n/4)+\Theta (1)+\Theta (1)=...=T(0)+\Theta (1)+\Theta (1)+\Theta (1)+...\Theta (1)=\Theta (1)+\Theta (1)+\Theta (1)...\Theta (1)(log_2n \Theta (1)s)=\Theta(log_2n)$

For the programming code, you can check it out at [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-peak-in-a-given-array/).